# Using Django models with an already created DB table

Tags: python, django

I have a DB (lets call it `data_db`) containing some tables. I want to create a dashboard to present data from `data_db`, so I created a Django project for that purpose.

When I want to get data from one of the tables in `data_db`, is there a way to do it with `Models`? (I want Django security management with the DB) or do I have to use raw SQL?

**One note**: there is existing data in the `data_db`'s table, and I don't want to create a new table with the same exact data on the default Django DB. I also use 2 DBs, Django default's and `data_db` and I created a database router for `data_db` to prevent Django from creating all its tables in there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. In fact Django can even help you create the models. Models that you do not migrate with the help of Django are *unmanaged* models. These have a `managed = False` attribute in the `Meta` class, so something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # … fields …
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

If you thus write these unmanaged models, you can make queries with the Django ORM, without Django trying to create new models for these tables.

Of course, specifying models that match with the database is cumbersome. Therefore Django can often construct models based on the tables. You can generate the models with the [**`inspectdb`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb).

You can generate these models on the `stdout` with:

```
python3 manage.py inspectdb
```

or you can save these to a file through I/O redirection:

```
python3 manage.py inspectdb > app_name/models.py
```