# Using a database modeler with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, navicat

I am trying to use Navicat as a visual way of designing the database Schema for a Django application.  I saw the `inspectdb` command for Django, but it seems for migrating an old database to a new one, not continuous changes as the application is developed.  What would the best way to integrate the both Navicat and Django together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a direct way Navicat can support your Model creation but you could use it to maintain the database schema and then use unmanaged models. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462553/using-django-models-with-an-already-created-db-table